# CodenameOne - GUI values from checkboxes, comboboxes and save captured photo to Cloud

Tags: checkbox, combobox, codenameone

I'm using NetBeans with CodenameOne and the theme GUI builder.
I have created a Main Form with checkboxes in a container, and comboboxes in another container. How can I use a GUI value from the checkboxes and the comboboxes in the StateMachine to save in Cloud Storage? I have also captured a photo to the Main Form and want to save all in Cloud Storage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial covering the process of getting state from components in GUI builder apps: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---handle-eventsnavigation-in-the-gui-builder--populate-the-form-from-code

Effectively you use something like `findMyCheckBox(f).isSelected()`, to find the state which you can then store anywhere you want (locally/cloud etc.).